# Is ConcurrentDictionary constructor thread safe?

Tags: c#

For example if I have code like:

```
if (dictionary == null) {
    dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary();
}
```

can multiple threads read that it's null and create new ConcurrentDictionaries at the same time?

I am talking about the ConcurrentDictionary provided by System.Collections.Concurrent

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In short, YES. the ConcurrentDictionary will make sure that it's accessing items, setting them etc is thread safe. There's not a lot it can do about another one being assigned to the same variable. You'd need to wrap the initialisation in some thread safety too.

Comment: Actually your question doesn't make sense. Constructors always return a new object, so if your code is going to potentially run with multiple threads, it's irrelevant that the constructor is thread-safe, but it is relavant that the code around it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ConcurrentDictionary` is thread safe. but code you have shown has nothing to do with internals of `ConcurrentDictionary`. everything out side `ConcurrentDictionary` is in your responsibility.  so you should make sure initialization is made only once.

One way to do that is using [Lazy(T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary> _dictionary = new Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary>(() => new ConcurrentDictionary());
```

Simply call Value to get instance of dictionary. Lazy will only initialize dictionary once and will also take care of thread safety for initialization part.

```
var dic = _dictionary.Value; // extract instance.
```

Answer (score 5):

Most constructors are thread-safe, because they are only happening on one thread. There are exceptions if they access static fields or invoke a non–thread-safe delegate or something, but they are rare (and generally a bad idea).

That's not the crux of your question though, because in your example, it's not the constructor that could be racing, but the assignment.

And if another thread could access `dictionary` then there is indeed a race, and one thread could assign to `dictionary` just to be overwritten by another thread (and potentially have a period where two threads see `dictionary` as having different values).

Which **might** be a problem. It might merely be suboptimal (e.g. the concurrent dictionary is used as a cache and some cached values get lost and have to be re-calculated but things still work) or it might be disastrous. If `dictionary` is visible to more than one thread then you should lock and retest, use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` or `Lazy<ConcurrentDictionary>`.

Answer (score 0):

It's thread-safe *once it's been instantiated* (i.e. multiple threads can add/get to/from it without issues). In your case, you would need to make the statement that instantiates it thread-safe, which you would do by using the [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) keyword:

```
Object thisLock = new Object();
lock (thisLock) {
    if (dictionary == null) {
        dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary();
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to say:
The object of ConcurrentDictionary is thread safe after creation.
But in your code your are asking about the thread safety of your reference to the object.
In this case `dictionary` is a reference that is initially null and this reference itself is not thread safe except if you use lock like how pushkin suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The code example is not thread safe because it allows multiple threads to see the "dictionary" variable while null before the new operator has a change to assign the new instance.

Using a lock object and a lock statement works but add a lock variable and incurs a lock penalty every time the dictionary is used.

The following version does not require a lock variable and does not incur a lock penalty on every use of the dictionary field.

```
if( dictionary == null )
    Interlocked.CompareExchange( ref dictionary, new ConcurrentDictionary(), null );

dictionary.xxx()
```

- Keep in mind that ConcurrentDictionary is a generic type, so the new operator above will need to include the  type parameters.